# Java can't find my array

Tags: java

I am having a hard time because Java can't find my array a[] is it because I declared it inside the do-while loop? But when I declare it outside the do-while loop it has error. Can you help me?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
   //Input number of grades.
   System.out.print("Enter No. of Grades from 5-10: ");
   int grades=0;

   do{
       grades=in.nextInt();
       int a[]=new int[grades];
       for(int i=0; i<grades; i++){
           //Inputing the grades
           System.out.print("Grades Values: ");
           int temp=0;
           //checking whether the no. grades are less than 5 or more than 10
            if(grades>11 || grades<5){
           System.out.println("INVALID!!");
           System.out.println("Enter Valid Number of Grades: ");
            }
           do{
               temp=in.nextInt();
               //checking whether the user's input of grades' values is between 0 to 100
               if(temp<0 || temp>=101){
                   System.out.println("Invalid Grade!");
                   System.out.println("Enter Valid Grade: ");
               }
           }while(temp<0 || temp>=101);
           a[i]=temp;

       }   
   }while(grades>11 || grades<5); 

   //getting Highest grade
   int highest=a[0];
   for(int i=1; i<a.length;i++){
       if(a[i]>highest){
           highest=a[i];
       }
   }
   System.out.println(highest);


}
```

Comment: what "error" does it have when you declare it outside of the `do-while`?

Comment: "is it because I declared it inside the do-while loop" - **yes**

Comment: @MischaBehrend it said it Java returned: 1

Comment: @suraj when I declare it outside the do-while loop it has an error when I run it

Comment: can you add the snippet of how you declared outside?

Comment: Sharing the code you're running and the *actual error you're getting* would be helpful. Saying "it has an error" is really not very useful.

Answer (score 1):

> is it because I declared it inside the do-while loop?

Yes.

```
do {
    int[] a;
}
...

// a is not visible here, because it is declared within the do-block.
```

You should [read more about scoping](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/variable-scope-in-java/).

> But when I declare it outside the do-while loop it has error

It depends on how you do that. This should work:

```
int[] a;
do {
    grades = in.nextInt();
    a = new int[grades];
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @BrendanDelosAngeles If this answer helped you, consider accepting it. It's how stackoverflow works https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers